# My Game gets crashed on sudden with text message sent to deallocated instance 0x13b07370 ... Do know why

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

I am developing a game using chipmunk where we have to drag a moving image and place it in to a box. I am creating a bomb like creature in one class. When I click the bomb and start dragging in touch ended phase i have created a delegate for another class [PlayLayer] and pass the bomb to a method of that class `[delegate draggingFinishedForBomb:self];`. In this I check whether the bomb is in the box or not. Everything works fine but my game gets crashed randomly showing:

> [PlayLayer draggingFinishedForBomb:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x13b07370

I have release all the alloc ones in super dealloc. I can't find the cause.

Comment: 0x13b07370 is the address of the object in question... You can use NSLog or printf with %p to print it. Try doing that, that could help you to solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for you response i will try to solve the issue

Comment: A case for Zombie objects, enable them in the target's scheme. You'll get more info about the deallocated object. Probably over-released an object.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Hi please help me out to solve this issue  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049459/the-revolute-joint-bodies-gets-scattered-when-touch-moved .....   I'm in need of your help